Dropped threads when trying to run multiple Aspen Plus instances via Python script
I had to come up with a fairly complex FT-based process in Aspen Plus. The task is to calculate plant efficiency for varying boundary conditions. Because the calculations take a very long time, I am trying to use random forrest regression to estimate plant efficiency. The approach is to use a python script to access Aspen Plus via the COM interface to generate a large data set. In order to limit machine time, I would like to have multiple instances of Aspen Plus running at the same time. To do so I am using the multiprocessing toolbox to generate a pool of asynchronous workers. While the script works flawlessly for a single instance and when multi-threaded calculations are limited to several hundred cases, it starts to drop threads for larger data sets. The number of cases returned is random, but always a multiple of the number of Jobs designated to a thread.
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import win32com.client as win32
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import pandas as pd # for working with DataFrames
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # for splitting the data
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error # for calculating the cost function
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor # for building the model
import pylab

start_time = time.time()
simulation_result = []

###############################################################################
#Calculation options
###############################################################################

JobsPerProcessor = 500
NumberOfProcessors = 10

###############################################################################
# Boundary condtions
###############################################################################

T_min = 600
T_max = 1000

p_min = 1
p_max =20

boundaries = [JobsPerProcessor, T_min, T_max, p_min, p_max]

###############################################################################
# Function to access Aspen Simulation
###############################################################################

def RunAspenSimulation(boundaries):
    
    process = mp.current_process()
    pid = process.name
    
    results = []
     
    # Create Aspen Plus Object
    aspen = win32.Dispatch('Apwn.Document')
    
    # Open the file
    aspen.InitFromArchive2(os.path.abspath('Reformerbsp/240717_Reformer_v1.bkp'))
    
    for point in range(boundaries[0]):
        
        # Random boundary conditions
        temperature = random.uniform(boundaries[1], boundaries[2])
        pressure = random.uniform(boundaries[3], boundaries[4]) 
        
        # Set Variables
        aspen.Tree.FindNode('/Data/Blocks/REFORMER/Input/TEMP').Value = temperature
        aspen.Tree.FindNode('/Data/Blocks/REFORMER/Input/PRES').Value = pressure
        
        # Run simulation
        aspen.Engine.Run2()
        
        # Get results
        x_CH4 =  aspen.Tree.FindNode('/Data/Streams/SYNGAS/Output/MOLEFRAC/MIXED/CH4').Value
        x_CO = aspen.Tree.FindNode('/Data/Streams/SYNGAS/Output/MOLEFRAC/MIXED/CO').Value
        x_CO2 = aspen.Tree.FindNode('/Data/Streams/SYNGAS/Output/MOLEFRAC/MIXED/CO2').Value
        x_H2 = aspen.Tree.FindNode('/Data/Streams/SYNGAS/Output/MOLEFRAC/MIXED/H2').Value
        x_H2O = aspen.Tree.FindNode('/Data/Streams/SYNGAS/Output/MOLEFRAC/MIXED/H2O').Value
        
        results.append([temperature, pressure, x_CH4, x_CO, x_CO2, x_H2, x_H2O])
        
        print("Worker", pid, "finished Job ", point)
               
    aspen.Close()
    
    print("Worker", pid, "calculations finished")
    
    return results

###############################################################################
# Single threaded calculations
###############################################################################

def SingleprocessAspen(boundaries):

    simulation_result = RunAspenSimulation(boundaries)
    
    print("elapsed time %s" % (time.time() - start_time))
    
    return simulation_result

###############################################################################
# Fetching results
###############################################################################

def collect_results(result):
    simulation_result.extend(result)

###############################################################################
# Multiprocessing
###############################################################################

def MultiprocessAspen(boundaries, NumberOfProcessors):
    # Create a pool of processors. Each processor will have one instance of Aspen Plus to work with
    pool = mp.Pool(NumberOfProcessors)
    
    for i in range(NumberOfProcessors):
        pool.apply_async(RunAspenSimulation,(boundaries,),callback=collect_results) 
        
    # Close parallel worker pool
    pool.close()

    # Wait for asynchronous calculations to finish
    pool.join()
    
    print("elapsed time %s" % (time.time() - start_time))
    
    return simulation_result

###############################################################################
# Run Regression
###############################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    simulation_result = SingleprocessAspen(boundaries)
   # simulation_result = MultiprocessAspen(boundaries, NumberOfProcessors)  

    ###########################################################################
    # Formatting of Data
    ###########################################################################

    Sim_out = np.array(simulation_result)
    
    print("datapoints:", len(simulation_result))
    
    dataset = pd.DataFrame({'temperature': Sim_out[:, 0], 'pressure': Sim_out[:, 1], 'x_CH4': Sim_out[:, 2], 'x_CO': Sim_out[:, 3], 'x_CO2': Sim_out[:, 4], 'x_H2': Sim_out[:, 5], 'x_H2O': Sim_out[:, 6]})
    
    ###############################################################################
    # Random Forest Regression
    ###############################################################################

    # Splitting input data into input (x) and output (y) data

    x = dataset[['temperature', 'pressure']] #Input

    y = dataset[['x_CH4','x_CO','x_CO2', 'x_H2', 'x_H2O']]  # Output

    # Splitting the dataset into training and testing set (80/20)

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 28)

    # Initializing the Random Forest Regression model with 10 decision trees

    model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)

    # Fitting the Random Forest Regression model to the data

    model.fit(x_train, y_train)

    # Predicting the target values of the test set

    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

    # Calculating Root Mean Square Error and mean error for evaluation

    rmse = float(format(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)),'.3f'))
    mean_error = rmse ** 0.5

    print("mean error:", mean_error)

    # Test prediction
    pred_array = pd.DataFrame({'temperature': [800], 'pressure': [8]})

    y_data = model.predict(pred_array)

    print('results:', y_data)

    plt.scatter(Sim_out[:,0], Sim_out[:,1])
    plt.show()
          
    print("elapsed time %s" % (time.time() - start_time))

I am expecting to recieve a set of Jobs per processer * workers datapoints. For the single threaded calculations and for less than 100 datapoints this works. Beyond that it seems like workers are dropped or results are not fetched correctly.
I have tried a minimal case without the connection to Aspen Plus and that does generate the data set without issues.
